# How to remove function from file on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

We have in our project several files that contains implementation of functions, what I need is to find in one of the files:

1. The specific location where a function is declared
2. Remove the function - meaning- the line where it start and the following 4 lines.

How can it be done using bash commands?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself

Comment: Hi, the thing is- I don't know how it can be done, so I have don't have a code that I tried.  I can run grep on the file to find the function name, but it does not help me in removing this line and the following 4 lines

Comment: please provide a sample source file and the desired result; what research and testing have you done?

Comment: if you already use grep then it can tell you line number. with head | tail you can print some lines. you can redirect stdout with >> into new file (two times will concatenate). if new file looks good you can cat file > origin (single redirect will overwrite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `sed`. The exact command would depend on the function (and language) that you are trying to remove. In general, you can use `sed -i '/STARTING_PATTERN/,/ENDING_PATTERN/d' file.ext` to delete from `STARTING_PATTERN` to `ENDING_PATTERN`. Say you have a C function (obviously this is a dummy example):

```
double toDouble(int input) {
    double output = (double)input;
    return output;
}
```

You could use `sed -i '/^double toDouble(int input) {$/,/^}$/d' file.c`. This will delete from a line that has only the signature of the function (`double toDouble(int input) {`) to the next line that has only a `}` on it. Obviously you will need to tailor your starting and ending patterns to whatever the function you are trying to match looks like. The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a line.

Edit: fixing typo

Comment: How is the '$' in front of 'double toDouble' correct?

Comment: Oh you are right, I will edit to fix that. Should be a `^` at the beginning.